# mysql: reversed content col for LIKE '%foo' - good practise?

Tags: mysql

I was recently watching a google lecture on mysql and learnt that MySQL wont use indexes for `LIKE '%foo'` searches.

My site's 'live search' (ajax search) searches the column `full_details(TEXT)`, should i create a reversed version like `full_details_rev(TEXT)` and index that?

Or should i not index large text fields at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fulltext searching (which is basically what you're doing), the [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html&prmdo=1&tbo=1) is much more efficient - for a brief intro, see e.g. [this article](http://ersinacar.com/using-fulltext-indexes-in-mysql-part-1_186.html); Google for more.

Example of use (assuming there is a fulltext index, otherwise you'll just get an error):

```
SELECT some_column FROM yourtable WHERE MATCH (full_details) AGAINST ('foo')
```

(a normal index on a reversed column would help you iff the original **ends exactly** with the search string (i.e. 'asdfsdafsdfaaaaafoo')

Comment: ah so the keyword would have to be on either end? bugger.

Comment: looks like you need to use the * wildcard instead of % for fulltext, search is that right?

Comment: @Haroldo: No. Fulltext search has its own syntax, added example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an external fulltext indexing tool like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: For high(er) volume of searches, Sphinx is a godsend. It might be a slight overkill here though...